# Does anybody know what a ~BROMIUM directory is? It was related to a svg file

Tags: git, github, svg, directory

For some reason a directory ~BROMIUM was created when I added a svg file in my assets/img directory.
When I pushed my git working branch to my remote GitHub branch nothing was wrong. I could also merge the branch with the development branch. But when I pulled the development branch it got the error message:

> cannot create directory at 'assets/img/~BROMIUM': No such file or directory

I solved it by deleting the folder ~BROMIUM (what contained for some reason the svg file) in my GitHub development branch, and then I was able to pull everything correctly.

But I am wondering what caused this? I did not created the folder myself and I could not find any information about it.

Comment: Could be a directory from [Bromium Secure Platform](https://documentation.bromium.com/4_0/Deployment%20Guide/Bromium_Secure_Platform_Deployment_Guide_4_0_Update_4.pdf#page=35)?

Comment: @phd That could be part of HP laptop security software. And that the laptop created the folder while copying the downloaded SVG as protection.

Comment: @rickhekman di you find any fix for this problem ?

Answer (score 7):

If you have a HP computer...This folder is created by Bromium:

From a manual of the app:
In each folder that contains untrusted files, there may be a hidden ~bromium folder and files appended with.bromium. The ~bromium folder contains meta files, one for each untrusted file..bromium files contain metadata that identifies an untrusted file.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed this problem by restarting my hp laptop. I have stopped the "HP Secure Click" service on the Task Manager, and then I was able to delete the directory.

Comment: What about simply ignoring all "~BROMIUM" folders on gitignore? Would it also work?